# What is a good undergraduate bioorganic chemistry book?

Tags: reference-request, books

What is a good undergraduate bioorganic chemistry book? I would like one of these as I'm tired of non-university books on the subject.

Comment: Voet, D.; Voet, J. G. Biochemistry, 4th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2011. [From this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)

Comment: Could you specify what sort of topics you want to be covered?